# Is there a formula for determining the focal point of a sphere?

Tags: optics

I guess this is the same as for cylinders, when light is shone through parallel to the cross-section, but Google-ing this only turns up lenses like the ones used in glasses.

I'm looking for something like what's described in this article: http://spie.org/x34513.xml

I hope to determine the veracity of the equation described there.

Comment: Does [this link](http://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/astro/heilig.htm) help?

Comment: DarkLightA: doesn't your own link answer your question?

Comment: Thanks Gugg! Make it an answer!

Colin K, it was the only source I could find, so I was somewhat skeptical.

Comment: Also, is there a way to determine how much will be reflected backwards off a side of a sphere, compared to what passes through?

Comment: I found [this](http://www.osti.gov/bridge/servlets/purl/108088-WCxlhc/webviewable/108088.pdf) (pdf-alert).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At your request. Here's [somebody](http://mysite.du.edu/~jcalvert/astro/heilig.htm) working it out for you.